# Include CakePHP constants into external web application

Tags: php, cakephp, constants, cakephp-2.1, external-application

I should have access to CakePHP constants in an external application on the same server.

What is best practise to include parts of a CakePHP application, to access them?

already tried to include bootstrap.php:

`Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found in /Users/Patrick/Sites/project/Config/bootstrap.php on line 27`

line 27 in bootstrap.php:

`Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));`

Comment: what exactly are your global vars? usually there are none in such a framework. they all have some scope or are accessed by wrappers like session, configure, ...

Comment: I need APP and CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH for this external application.

Comment: my fault, changed title. need one more coffee :)

Comment: You probably need to include the index.php or copy and paste some of it (without the dispatcher part).

Comment: just tested, but there's following error: `Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found in /Users/Patrick/Sites/project/Config/bootstrap.php on line 27`

line 27 in bootstrap.php:
`Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to make a plugin for it. That creates a separation of concerns. Just including parts from Cake into another piece of software will create a mess likely. Think about what happens when CakePHP Framework get's to a new version. After a while it is totally unclear what is integrated and what not while you have to check only your plugin(s) to see the integration in the other case.

Comment: sounds logical, i'll create a plugin for this.
Thanks for answering!